# Linq query to include and filter grandchildren itens

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following database structure in SQL Server

```
create table dbo.tebwf_versao
(
    cd_workflow int NOT NULL,
    cd_versao int NOT NULL,
    nm_workflow varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    constraint pkebwf_versao primary key (cd_workflow, cd_versao)
);

create table dbo.tebwf_versao_det
(
    cd_workflow int NOT NULL,
    cd_versao int NOT NULL,
    cd_detalhe int not null,
    dc_referencia varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    constraint pkebwf_versao_det primary key (cd_workflow, cd_versao, cd_detalhe),
    constraint fkebwf_versao_det__versao foreign key (cd_workflow, cd_versao)
        references dbo.tebwf_versao (cd_workflow,  cd_versao)
);

create table dbo.tebwf_versao_det_passo
(
    cd_workflow int NOT NULL,
    cd_versao int NOT NULL,
    cd_detalhe int not null,
    cd_passo smallint not null,
    nm_passo varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    constraint pkebwf_versao_det primary key (cd_workflow, cd_versao, cd_detalhe, cd_passo),
    constraint fkebwf_versao_det_passo__versao_det foreign key (cd_workflow, cd_versao, cd_detalhe)
        references dbo.tebwf_versao_det (cd_workflow, cd_versao, cd_detalhe)
);
```

The query I'm trying to replicate the following SQL query, and already bringing all the objects in a single Linq query with Include:

```
select *
from dbo.tebwf_versao vs 
join dbo.tebwf_versao_det vsd on vs.cd_workflow = vsd.cd_workflow
                                and vs.cd_versao = vsd.cd_versao
join dbo.tebwf_versao_det_passo vsdp on vsd.cd_workflow = vsdp.cd_workflow
                                        and vsd.cd_versao = vsdp.cd_versao
                                        and vsd.cd_detalhe = vsdp.cd_detalhe
where vs.cd_workflow = 3
  and vs.cd_versao = 1
  and vsd.cd_detalhe = 1
  and vsdp.cd_passo = 1;
```

Going through several posts, the recommendation is to use the `Any` command, and I've build the following Query:

```
var workflows = EBwfVersaos
    .Include(wfv => wfv.EBwfVersaoDets
        .Select(wfvd => wfvd.EBwfVersaoDetPassoes_CdDetalhe))
    .Where(wfv => wfv.CdWorkflow == 3 && wfv.CdVersao == 1
        && wfv.EBwfVersaoDets.Any(wfvd => wfvd.CdDetalhe == 1 &&
            wfvd.EBwfVersaoDetPassoes_CdDetalhe.Any (wfvdp => wfvdp.CdPasso == 1))).ToList();
```

However, this query does not render the same result set, since the brings a row from `EBwfVersaos (tebwf_versao)` if I have at least one row from *EBwfVersaoDets (tebwf_versao_det)* with a value of 1, but if I have 4 rows in that table with `cd_workflow = 3` and `cd_versao = 1`, but with `cd_detalhe` equals to 1, 2, 3 and 4, all of them are returned by the Linq statement. I would like to have returned only the 1 row with the value of `cd_detalhe` = 1. The same applies to the second subquery. I also tried Linq Expression:

```
var workflows = 
    (from wf in EBwfWorkflows.Where(wf => wf.CdProduto == 1 && wf.CdEvento == 1)
    join wfv in EBwfVersaos.Where(wfv => wfv.CdVersao == 1)
        on wf.CdWorkflow equals wfv.CdWorkflow 
    join wfvd in EBwfVersaoDets.Where(wfvd => wfvd.CdDetalhe == 1)
        on new { wfv.CdWorkflow, wfv.CdVersao} equals new {wfvd.CdWorkflow, wfvd.CdVersao}
    select new {wf = wf, wfv = wfv, wfvd = wfvd}).ToList();
```

It works, but the results are not related, and I can't easily navigate between them. Besides the 3 tables below, I have several other related tables that I need to access, and it's being a real pain to get all the information I need into a single Linq query, while being able to filter, otherwise I'll get too much queried. Is there a way to have the include AND the where on those multiple levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this option isn't available on EntityFramework. However, you can try to use Entity Framework Plus: http://entityframework-plus.net/

To be more specific, you'll need run the following command on Nuget Package Manager:

Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilter.EF6 -Version 1.6.0

Then, in your code:

`using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;`

`...`

`var workflows = _Context.EBwfWorkflows
    .Where(w => w.CdProduto == 1 && w.CdEvento == 1)
    .IncludeFilter(w => w.EBwfVersaos.Where(v => v.CdVersao == 1))
    .Where(w => w.EBwfVersaos.Any())`

It will return only the "workflows" that have at least one EBwfVersao with CdVersao = 1 and also the workflows will have only the EBwfVersaos (workflow.EBwfVersaos) which have the CdVersao = 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked well.. just what I needed. Tks